# Which is better Branched if-else if construct vs continue statement in loop?

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, readability, continue

Out of the two code snippets below, does any of the approach has some benefit over the other?

```
for(int i:list) {
    if(condition 1) {
      //do something
      continue;
    }
    if(condition 2) {
      //do something
      continue;
    }
    if(condition 3) {
      //do something
      continue;
    }
}
```

versus

```
for(int i:list) {
    if(condition 1) {
      //do something
    }
    else if(condition 2) {
      //do something
    }
    else if(condition 3) {
      //do something
    }
}
```

Do the two approaches differ only in coding style or do we get any performance improvement in one of them.

Comment: Prefer whichever is most readable. The JIT can easily transform a->b where b is whichever version is "better".

Comment: In the second example, it is recognizable that an `if` will not be entered into if a previous `if` has already been entered into.

Comment: in addition to the other comments, `continue;` is taking an extra line per condition :)

Comment: `if-else if` is easier to read and presents the desired logic better - IMHO